# Is there a method of performing "local arp" requests on linux

Tags: linux, linux-networking, arp

I have some code that performs an arp-scan, I wondered if there was a way within a single machine to have "something" respond to arp-scan within the same host.

I've tried a few things so far like macvlans/ipvlans (l2) etc but I think perhaps it's just not possible due to the nature of ARP.

The flow is this:

I have an application that performs an arp-scan on startup, and I want to "mock" a response to the arp-scan so it gets the mac and IP address of another interface on the same host.

Comment: What is the overall aim for this? It sounds like an XY problem...

Comment: Try proxy ARP maybe?

Comment: I've added some detail to the question. I've looked at proxyarp but I again couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Also I've never heard of an xy problem before, this could well be one. The easiest solution would be to just modify the code so that it doesn't actually need a proper arp response, but this nerd sniped me in a way where it looks like this should sort of be possible, but then again might not ;)